# Cannot use MySqlConnection after initialization. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, connection, initialization

I downloaded MySql Connector/NET, and set it as a reference in my project.
I added the `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` to my code.

Now I tried initializing a connection like this:

```
MySqlConnection test = new MySqlConnection(Utilities.GenerateMySqlConnectionString("localhost", "test", "root", ""));
```

However I cannot use this object later. Looks like the IDE doesn't recognize it. Here's a screenshot to explain better.
[IDE Screenshot http://n.muboo.net/NoMySQLConnection.png](http://n.muboo.net/NoMySQLConnection.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you at this point?  If you're at the class level, it's expecting you to declare a method, property, field, event, etc, and won't show you any fields in intellisense.

Comment: Oh my god, dummy me. Thank you, I hadn't noticed at all! I feel like I'm wasting StackOverflow's bandwidth.